# Windows 8.1 broadcom wireless 802.11abgn

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers

My Broadcom 802.11abgn wireless sdio adapter stopped working out of nowhere

I already tried :

- 3 Driver reinstall from official driver download page (both Broadcom
  and Asus)
- 2 Factory resets.

Checked via CMD if the adaptor was giving me ping problems.

**Error screenshots below**
[image]

[image]

This is the computer: [ASUS EeeBook X205TA](http://www.asus.com/Commercial-Notebooks/ASUS_EeeBook_X205TA/HelpDesk/)

Comment: What exactly seems to be the problem ? not detecting wireless networks, not connecting to a network ?

Comment: My bad im editing it with screenshots

Comment: 5.93.103.20
try that version, i'm using it for win10

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, that cross mark on the internet symbol gave me a nightmare. I have a toshiba laptop, so I installed and started Config application (I got from the toshiba website). This app starts the wifi card. So, search for a similar functionality application for asus. From the device manager, try to uninstall the driver, after the uninstallation the windows 10 installs the driver from the inbuilt signatures. The installed driver version will be 6.30.xxx.xx

If you still face the issue, after trying these methods, please comment it here.